# Android Studio (build.gradle) - Error: starting process 'command '..\bin\cmake.exe''

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake

I was working normally for a few hours today, after i got the error described in the title after compiling native code. I do not changed anything on my environment in the meanwhile and i compiled  my native C code (x-1)th time without problems, but now i am not able to use cmake anymore.

**Already tried**

- I had two versions of cmake installed. As Android Studio once
  suggested to install cmake, i uninstalled cmake 3.4 (i believe) and
  3.6 and reinstalled it. After getting an error about missing cmake.exe (indeed the executable was missing
  ..\sdk\cmake\\bin\ ) i reinstalled cmake again by checking
  for the cmake.exe constantly. Now cmake.exe is there but the compile
  process is not working anyway.
- The log files idea.log and build.log (from the log files in "Show Log
  in Explorer" nearby "Try Again") are only showing INFO messages and
  there is nothing looking mad to me.
- I have CMake installed separately too on my machine too and the
  command is added in environmental variable path but from CMake
  homepage there is no way to download older versions than 3.7 (i have 
  the latest 3.8). BTW i have no idea how to link it with Android
  Studio - it is not possible from the settings.

**Problem**
So contrary to most of the other questions which states they are not finding CMake in the SDK-Tools list, mine stopped working after a few month of normal usage! Any suggestion to solve this problem is very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem was an update of a sdk-tool and the build.gradle not configured accordingly. Though i have not noticed any update in that moment and i do not got it to work.
A clean reinstall of the IDE with the originally downloaded file solved the problem (Note: Android Studio preserves the project files and configuration files). After downloading all needed tools and updating the build.gradle file step by step worked without problems for me.

I have to say that my actual AS-version is 2.3.1, the previous (updated) version was 2.3.3...

This is not the answer i was looking for, so if anyone finds a better solution i will update the best answer respectively!